# Update a table such that multiple users get a new row

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table called grades that has this:

```
user   assignment   mark
a      a1           NULL
a      a2           NULL
b      a1           5
b      a2           NULL
```

I want to update this table and add a new assignment to each row for each unique user , For example adding a3 to each user:

```
user   assignment   mark
a      a1           NULL
a      a2           NULL
a      a3           NULL
b      a1           5
b      a2           NULL
b      a3           NULL
```

Is there a way to do this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT username FROM grades 
INSERT INTO grades VALUES (username, 'a3', NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
INSERT INTO grade SELECT DISTINCT `user`,'a3',NULL FROM grade
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got all users first of all. And user gets a number of the row. For example, two row get then row-wise insert user and assignment.